# I need to validate dob in dd/mm/yy format (with leap year) with age validation - Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

The age should be between 15-80. Below is my code for the validation, but doesn't seem to work:

I haven't done age validation though.

function isValidDate(dob) {

```
var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value;
// First check for the pattern
if(!/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/.test(dob))
    result = false;

// Parse the date parts to integers
var parts = dob.split("/");
var day = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
var month = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
var year = parseInt(parts[2], 10);

// Check the ranges of month and year
if(year < 1000 || year > 3000 || month == 0 || month > 12)
    result = false;

var monthLength = [ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 ];

// Adjust for leap years
if(year % 400 == 0 || (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0))
    monthLength[1] = 29;

// Check the range of the day
return day > 0 && day <= monthLength[month - 1];
```

};

Comment: Instead of searching why don't you write one?

Comment: Please share first your code and if you stuck somewhere ask for help.

Comment: @KrutiPatel Sorry. I've added. Please take a look.

Comment: You could write it yourself, but why not just use moment.js - takes so much of the pain out of dealing with dates in JS

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the comment of @PerryW, this is an implementation using [Moment.JS](http://momentjs.com/)

```
var moment = require('moment');
var dateString = document.getElementById("dob").value;

var dob = moment(dateString);

// Age validation
var now = moment();
var minDob = now.subtract(81, 'years').add(1, 'days');
var maxDob = now.subtract(15, 'years');

if (dob.isBetween(minDob, maxDob, 'day')) {
  // Person is between 15 and 80 years old
} else {
  // Person is too young or too old
}
```